# Unable to perform button click in nightwatch.js using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm currently new to automation testing and performing automation tests with nightwatch.js using selenium-webdriver, I'm trying to perform automation testing  on a flight search flow for a website, I'm currently having trouble performing the click for a specific button.

The following are the different click commands that I had tried, which unfortunately didn't work  for that specific button. I've tried to locate the button element using ID,Class as well as Xpath selectors but it wasn't working for any of it, and when executing the script the script stops at that point and when when assertions were passed it says " The specific element could not be located"

```
 'continue booking': function (browser) {
    browser
      .waitForElementVisible('#booking_un_step_1', 10000)
      .click('#booking_un_step_1')
      },
```

This is the second way that I tried,

```
'continue booking': function (browser) {
    browser
      .execute(function (selector) {
        document.querySelector(selector).click();
      }, ['#booking_un_step_1'])
      },
```

and this as well,

```
'continue booking': function (browser) {
    browser

      .execute(function(browser){
        document.getElementById('#booking_un_step_1').click()
      })
      },
```

and lastly I tried this as well,

```
'continue booking': function (browser) {
    browser

     .click().keys("t",function(done){
        browser
        .pause(5000)
        .expect.element('#booking_un_step_1').to.have.css('display').which.equals('inline-block');

      })
  },
```

and this is the button that I want to perform the click on,

```
<button style="margin-left: 6px;" id="booking_un_step_1" type="button" name="next" class=" opn_booking_module_email_or_login btn-new-ui action-button">Continue Booking</button>
```

Kindly help me out with this issue,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try with this selector `button[id="booking_un_step_1" ][name="next"]`

Comment: Hi, @BaoTran thank you for that but unfortunately that didn't work for for me , when I tried it like this [Link] (https://jsfiddle.net/nu000e6q/) it gave me a "Reference Error": Button  not defined
and when tried this way [Link] (https://jsfiddle.net/sqo4aqfq/) the click wasn't performed.

Comment: Please execute this and return me the result` browser
      .waitForElementVisible('button[id="booking_un_step_1"]', 10000)
      .click('button[id="booking_un_step_1"]')`

Comment: Says " The Element booking_un_step_1 is visible" but the click still doesn't perform.

Comment: Is your element visible on screen (and not below the fold)?

Comment: it could be because the element is not shown on the screen. You must scroll first to it. Nightwatch has method `moveToElement` http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#moveToElement.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the below one. This has worked well for me

```
.waitForElementVisible('button[name=next]', 1000)
.click('button[name=next]')
```